# Error in initialization of pointer results in write access violation

Tags: c++, pointers

I am having some trouble with pointers. I have a class

```
class Foo
{
private:
   int var;
public:
   Foo() = default;
   void SetVar(int v) {var = v;}
};
```

to which I need to create a pointer in another class:

```
class Object
{
private:
   Foo* ptr;
public:
   Object() = default;
   void func()
   {
      ptr->SetVar(10);
   }

};
```

This gives me a write access violation. I think that the problem is with the initialization of `ptr`, but I don't know how to remedy that problem. Thank you!

Comment: There is no initialization of `Object::ptr` and that's the problem. The default constructor is insufficient and assuming `Object` is supposed to retain ownership of a `Foo` created in `Object`'s constructor the destructor won't do the trick either...

Comment: And don't bother with lines like `Foo() = default;` until you know why (in a few cases) they are needed (the posted code doesn't).

Comment: Did you initialized  `Foo` by `new` or address of `member field`?

Comment: You will need to create an object `Foo` and point `ptr` to it. Depending on the purpose of the code, that can be done in various places, either the constructor of `Object`, or within `func`, or from another function

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `ptr` in `constructor` of `Object` class and `delete` it in `destructor`! or use `smart pointers`!

declared `ptr` as

```
Foo* ptr = nullptr;
```

add definition for `Object()` as

```
Object::Object()
{
    ptr = new Foo();
}
```

and definition for `~Object()` as

```
Object::~Object()
{
    if (ptr != nullptr)
    {     
        delete ptr;
        ptr = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to not dynamically allocate the variables. Is there any way to not have to?

Comment: I have been studying the Windows API, where you write code like this: `m_pRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Black), &m_pBlackBrush);` Is there anyway to implement this technique, where you pass a reference into a function that then sets it equal to an instance, in my case?

Comment: @johndoe There no reference in that code (or anywhere in the Windows API which is based on C which does not have references). I think you are misunderstanding the `&` address of operator.

Comment: @johndoe But of course you can write code like the above in C++, just understand it doesn't use references.

Comment: If I were to try to do something like that, how would I keep the object from being destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

> I think that the problem is with the initialization of ptr

You could say that. You've failed to initialise the pointer before indirecting through the pointer to access an object that isn't being pointed at.

> I don't know how to remedy that problem.

Step 1: Create an object of type `Foo`.

Step 2: Initialise the pointer with the address of the object created in step 1.

Step 3 and beyond: Make sure that the created object stays alive at least as long as the pointer does.

A minimal example:

```
class Object
{
    // ...
    explicit Object(Foo* ptr): ptr(ptr) {}; // Step 2


// usage
Foo f; // Step 1
{
    Object o{&f};
    o.func();
} // step 3
```

---

I recommend considering an alternative design where you store the `Foo` object as a member object, rather than pointing to an object stored elsewhere.

Comment: Would it be possible in this situation to use a std::unique_ptr?

Comment: @johndoe Possible, ure. But why use dynamic allocation unless you need it?